# $f(z_0)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}z_0^n + 1+1+ \dots$ - Dense on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, roots-of-unity

**Personal question :** Let $z_0$ be a $2^k$th root of unity. We obtain for the function $f(z)=\sum_{n \geq 0} z^{2^n}$ (radius of convergence $R=1$) that $f(z_0)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}z_0^n + 1+1+ \dots$. Why all such points is dense on the unit circle?

I tried to obtain results from that question, but I blocked. Is anyone could help me at this point?

Answer (score 1):

The $2^k$-th roots of unity are $e^{2\pi i \lambda},$ where $\lambda = \frac{a}{2^b}$ is a dyadic rational number. It's enough to know that dyadic rational numbers are dense in $[0,1]$. In other words, that any number in $[0,1]$ can be written as an infinite "decimal" expansion in base $2$.

Comment: Could you explain in details your last sentence?

Comment: In the same way that you would find the base $10$ expansion for $\frac{1}{7}$ by writing $\frac{999999}{7} = 142857$ and seeing that $\frac{1}{7} = 0.\overline{142857}...$, you can write $\frac{2^3 - 1}{7} = 1 = 001$ base $2$ and know that $\frac{1}{7}$ has base $2$ expansion $0.\overline{001}$. This is an intuitive way of understanding that $\frac{1}{7} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{3n}}$ and so it's a limit of dyadic rationals. Convince yourself that you can do this for any rational number - since these are dense in $[0,1]$ by definition, it will be enough.